# Create a user account for development in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, local, development

How to create a user account in which I install all apps needed locally, so as not to mess up my system? That way if anything goes wrong I can simply just remove the user account and create a new one.

Of course, the most important part is how to install the apps locally, either with apt or pip or npm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will likely be application-dependent. Some may exist as snap packages, flatpaks, or appimages (three ways to install somewhat "isolated" apps), that you can install without any risk for your system.

If you install regular apps (from source or else),what can mess the system isn't the application, but newer versions of libraries you have to install for this application, and these may be more difficult to install for a single user. But IMHO, by the time you get skilled enough to do this, you will be more confident to install the regular installs.

Otherwise, you can use a virtual machine.

Comment: I upvoted this because this is most of what I use, however you didn't add local sandboxed environments like Python virtual environments and local vs. global installs which I also use regularly to install development packages as a normal user in my home directory